# SQLite Full text search: Find rows that countains any of keywords

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I have following tables:

```
-- table to keep articles titles
CREATE TABLE articles(id, title);
insert into articles (id,title) values (1,'sqlite example');
insert into articles (id,title) values (2,'sqlite query ');
insert into articles (id,title) values (3,'erlang example ');
insert into articles (id,title) values (3,'erlang otp ');

-- table to keep keywords that we would like to search.
create table keywords(id,keyword);
insert into keywords (id,keyword) values  (1,'sqlite');
insert into keywords (id,keyword) values  (2,'otp');


-- full text search table - copy of articles.

create virtual table articles_fts using fts4 (id,name);

-- populate table with articles titles.
insert into articles_fts(id,name) select id,title from articles;
```

Now I would like to find **ALL articles** that contains any of specified keywords.

Query like:

```
select * from articles_fts 
  where name match (select keyword from keywords);
```

returns only titles with sqlite in it (first keyword), so the other entries of keywords table are  ignored.

**Question:**
How could I find all articles that contains any of specified keywords?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
select *
  from articles_fts
 WHERE articles_fts MATCH ( select group_concat(keyword, ' OR ')
                              from keywords
                             group by 'x' )
```

The `group_concat` function aggregates all keywords with a comma. If you replace commas with OR, it should produce a good FTS query.

Also see section 3 of [the full text search feature reference](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) regarding the OR keyword and the [reference for aggregate functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).

Comment: Looks like it does not work: 'Error: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause', If I do it without `GROUP BY 1`', there are no error, but query returns no rows :(

Comment: @Anton Prokoiev: I use  `group by 1` as a constant and forgot that it is interpreted as a column reference, try `group by 'x'` instead

Comment: Thanks it works. The only one remark: your query should look like: `Select * from articles_fts where articles_fts MATCH (select group_concat (keyword,' OR ') from keywords group by 'x');`. **So ' OR ' should be UPPER CASE**   in other case it does not interred as an keyword :)